# how to make my css header responsive

Tags: html, css

Im using this CSS:

```
#header-topbar {
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
    padding-top:5px;
}
#header-right-content {
    float:right;
    margin-right:14%;
    margin-top:20px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:right;
    color:#000000;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 360px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

for my header and i want to make it responsive. i know how to use the media queries but im not sure about the rest of the css.

how do i make it so the logo div displays at the top, centered and then the text to display below?

i have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bMsMw/ so you can see the html

thanks

Answer (score 2):

check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bMsMw/2/)

in `#header-topbar` to make easy to manipulate in `media query` height should not state,
in `#logo` is there reason why you `position:absolute` that is one reason why your logo not go down because of `absolute:position` it display on the top of element,

```
#header-topbar {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:5px;
}
#header-right-content {
    float:right;
    margin-right:14%;
    margin-top:20px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:right;
    color:#000000;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 360px;
    height: 50px;
}
#logo img {
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
}
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 620px){
    #logo{
        width:70%;
        float:none;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
    #header-right-content {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }

}
```

hope this help you..

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/bMsMw/1/
Not exactly sure how the image should fit.

```
code
```